# Java.io.NotSerializableException: org.apache.storm.tuple.TupleImpl in Storm BaseStatefulWindowedBolt (2.2.0)

Tags: serialization, apache-storm

My storm topology (2.2.0) crashes sometimes with:

```java
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.io.NotSerializableException: org.apache.storm.tuple.TupleImplException
```

in a bolt extending the *BaseStatefulWindowedBolt* (my "windowbolt").

Interestingly, this seems to happen only when some throughput level is reached or network latency / packet loss occurs (I inject such network conditions on one of the storm docker containers for bench-marking purposes).
After one of this bolts' tasks failed, the others usually also do after some point and the topology is not able to recover from that failure in a state-ful way.

As the exception seems to not involve any custom classes i am quite unsure about the reason behind the failure.
Is this possibly an implementation / configuration problem on my side, or a problem / maybe even normal behavior of Apache storm under these conditions?

- Error fetched by the storm cli:

```java
{"Comp-Errors":{"windowbolt":"java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.io.NotSerializableException: org.apache.storm.tuple.TupleImpl\n\tat org.apache.storm.utils.Utils$1.run(Utils.java:409)\n\tat java.base\/java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)\nCaused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.io.NotSerializableException: org.apache.storm.tuple.TupleImpl\n\tat org.apache.storm.executor.Executor.accept(Executor.java:290)\n\tat org.apache.storm.utils.JCQueue.consumeImpl(JCQueue.java:131)\n\tat org.apache.storm.utils.JCQueue.consume(JCQueue.java:111)\n\tat org.apache.storm.executor.bolt.BoltExecutor$1.call(BoltExecutor.java:172)\n\tat org.apache.storm.executor.bolt.BoltExecutor$1.call(BoltExecutor.java:159)\n\tat org.apache.storm.utils.Utils$1.run(Utils.java:394)\n\t... 1 more\nCaused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.io.NotSerializableException: org.apache.storm.tuple.TupleImpl\n\tat org.apache.storm.serialization.SerializableSerializer.write(SerializableSerializer.java:36)\n\tat com.esotericsoftware.kryo.Kryo.writeClassAndObject(Kryo.java:628)\n\tat com.esotericsoftware.kryo.serializers.CollectionSerializer.write(CollectionSerializer.java:100)\n\tat com.esotericsoftware.kryo.serializers.CollectionSerializer.write(CollectionSerializer.java:40)\n\tat com.esotericsoftware.kryo.Kryo.writeObject(Kryo.java:534)\n\tat org.apache.storm.serialization.KryoValuesSerializer.serializeInto(KryoValuesSerializer.java:38)\n\tat org.apache.storm.serialization.KryoTupleSerializer.serialize(KryoTupleSerializer.java:40)\n\tat org.apache.storm.daemon.worker.WorkerTransfer.tryTransferRemote(WorkerTransfer.java:116)\n\tat org.apache.storm.daemon.worker.WorkerState.tryTransferRemote(WorkerState.java:524)\n\tat org.apache.storm.executor.ExecutorTransfer.tryTransfer(ExecutorTransfer.java:68)\n\tat org.apache.storm.executor.bolt.BoltOutputCollectorImpl.boltEmit(BoltOutputCollectorImpl.java:112)\n\tat org.apache.storm.executor.bolt.BoltOutputCollectorImpl.emit(BoltOutputCollectorImpl.java:65)\n\tat org.apache.storm.task.OutputCollector.emit(OutputCollector.java:93)\n\tat org.apache.storm.task.OutputCollector.emit(OutputCollector.java:93)\n\tat org.apache.storm.task.OutputCollector.emit(OutputCollector.java:93)\n\tat org.apache.storm.task.OutputCollector.emit(OutputCollector.java:93)\n\tat org.apache.storm.task.OutputCollector.emit(OutputCollector.java:42)\n\tat org.apache.storm.topology.WindowedBoltExecutor.execute(WindowedBoltExecutor.java:313)\n\tat org.apache.storm.topology.PersistentWindowedBoltExecutor.execute(PersistentWindowedBoltExecutor.java:137)\n\tat org.apache.storm.topology.StatefulBoltExecutor.doExecute(StatefulBoltExecutor.java:145)\n\tat org.apache.storm.topology.StatefulBoltExecutor.handleTuple(StatefulBoltExecutor.java:137)\n\tat org.apache.storm.topology.BaseStatefulBoltExecutor.execute(BaseStatefulBoltExecutor.java:71)\n\tat org.apache.storm.executor.bolt.BoltExecutor.tupleActionFn(BoltExecutor.java:236)\n\tat org.apache.storm.executor.Executor.accept(Executor.java:283)\n\t... 6 more\nCaused by: java.io.NotSerializableException: org.apache.storm.tuple.TupleImpl\n\tat java.base\/java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(Unknown Source)\n\tat java.base\/java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(Unknown Source)\n\tat org.apache.storm.serialization.SerializableSerializer.write(SerializableSerializer.java:33)\n\t... 29 more\n"},"Topology Name":"KafkaTopology"}
```

- "windowbolt" implementation:

```java
public class StatefulWindowBolt extends BaseStatefulWindowedBolt<KeyValueState<String, AvgState>> {
    private OutputCollector collector;
    private Counter counter;
    private Counter windowCounter;
    private KeyValueState<String, AvgState> state;

    @Override
    public void prepare(Map stormConf, TopologyContext context, OutputCollector collector) {
        this.collector = collector;
        this.counter = context.registerCounter("WindowBolt_Executed");
        this.windowCounter = context.registerCounter("WindowBolt_WindowNumber");
    }

    @Override
    public void execute(TupleWindow inputWindow) {
        long window_sum = 0;
        long window_length = 0;
        long ts = 0;
        long max_ts = 0;
        long start_event_time = inputWindow.getStartTimestamp();
        long end_event_time = inputWindow.getEndTimestamp();
        long partition = -1;
        String note = "/";
        
        Map<String, AvgState> map = new HashMap<String, AvgState>();
        Iterator<Tuple> it = inputWindow.getIter();

        while (it.hasNext()) {
            Tuple tuple = it.next();
            if (window_length == 0){
                //same for whole window because of FieldsGrouping by partition
                partition = tuple.getIntegerByField("partition");
                note = tuple.getStringByField("note");
            }
            Long sensordata = tuple.getLongByField("sensordata");
            window_sum += sensordata;
            ts = tuple.getLongByField("timestamp");

            if (ts > max_ts) {
                max_ts = ts;
            } else {
                //
            }
            String city = tuple.getStringByField("city");
            AvgState state = map.get(city);
            if (state == null){
                state = new AvgState(0,0);
            }
            map.put(city, new AvgState(state.sum+sensordata, state.count + 1));
            counter.inc();
            window_length++;
        }

        long window_avg = window_sum / window_length;

        // emit the results
        JSONObject json_message = new JSONObject();
        json_message.put("window_avg", window_avg);
        json_message.put("start_event_time", start_event_time);
        json_message.put("end_event_time", end_event_time);
        json_message.put("window_size", window_length);
        json_message.put("last_event_ts", max_ts);
        json_message.put("count_per_city", print(map));
        json_message.put("partition", partition);
        json_message.put("note", note);
        String kafkaMessage = json_message.toString();
        String kafkaKey = "window_id: " + windowCounter.getCount();

        collector.emit(new Values(kafkaKey, kafkaMessage));
        windowCounter.inc();
    }

    @Override
    public void declareOutputFields(OutputFieldsDeclarer declarer) {
        declarer.declare(new Fields("key", "message"));

    }
    public String print(Map<String, AvgState> map) {
        StringBuilder mapAsString = new StringBuilder("{");
        for (String key : map.keySet()) {
            AvgState state = map.get(key);
            mapAsString.append(key + "=" + state.count + ", ");
        }
        mapAsString.delete(mapAsString.length()-2, mapAsString.length()).append("}");
        return mapAsString.toString();
    }
    @Override
    public void initState(KeyValueState<String, AvgState> state) {
    this.state = state;
    }
}
```

in my main i set:

```java
config.setFallBackOnJavaSerialization(true);
config.registerSerialization(AvgState.class);
```

Comment: Are you sure that your class "AvgState" is serializable? I had a similar issue and wrote a test class in order to check if the objects are really serializable-

Comment: @moosehead42 For my understanding: if the class is not serializable, this topology could not work at any point right? This is my State class, it just holds 2 long variables:                    `class AvgState implements java.io.Serializable{
    public long sum;
    public long count;

    public AvgState(long sum, long count) {
        this.sum = sum;
        this.count = count;
    }
}`